# Is there any solution using stringbuilder to label text not converting string format?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

i want use dynamic string in label text.

but label text is static text so, i want modify or add some code.

i wonder is there no way to using stringbuilder to label text not convert string.

or if it can. help some code or method

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more ? It's not quite clear what you need ? Maybe you can show us with code.

Comment: label text is static text. but i want to using dynamic text in label without convert format.

Comment: `lblName.Text = "dynamic text";` ... `lblName.Text += " Some more text";` ? See what I mean, show us some code.

Comment: if you explain why you can't use existing label control you will get solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't get what's your mean when you say Dynamic String,
the only diffidence between make string using StringBuilder and String is 
when you append some word to string variable it get a new space in memory,
but stringBiulder use link list and don't waste memory when you append word by append method to it,
finally if you want to add some extra content to a label text you can do that simply by:

```
lbl.text += "your appended content";
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. If is just something that happen sometimes, replacing the property `Text` or appending some other string with `lbl.Text+="xxxxx"` would be fine. But if you want to create something as a console or a logger output, consider using a multiline readonly `TextBox`, so you can use [AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx), that is more efficient for such pourpose